# Android call method x times on day

Tags: android, timer

I want to start an Activity x times on day, even if the App is closed. But it should be on random time and not the same time each day. Preferably I can set a range of time, e.g.: the Activity should start 3 times between 7AM and 10PM.

Has anybody ANY idea to do this?

Comment: Try to use CountDownTimer and Service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: lis, I think you need to use timer within randon function.

Comment: no, that doesn't work when app doesn't run anymore (or cache is cleared). Tried it hard today :(